# Using Octal Number 08 and 09 and SCHTASKS

Tags: batch-file, octal

I had what I thought was a working script. Randomly decided to try month 09 and it failed. Also failed on month 08.

Googling and such has informed me this is because of `Octal Numbers` which are base 8 from what I can tell.

I am not sure how to best address this issue for my needs and could use a bit of advice.

This date is being used to create tasks via `SCHTASKS` which requires a 2 digit Month/Day and 4 digit Year

It keeps looping back to the beginning when 08 and 09 are used for the Month. I assume it would apply to the Day as well. Unsure what other number might be affected also.

```
:SETDATE
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO Date must be 2 digit Month/Day and 4 digit Year
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P SETMONTH=Enter 2 digit month for the restart (01-12):
ECHO.
SET /P SETDAY=Enter 2 digit day for the restart (01-31):
ECHO.
SET /P SETYEAR=Enter 4 digit year for the restart (2019-2025):

IF %SETMONTH% LSS 1 GOTO SETDATE
IF %SETMONTH% GTR 12 GOTO SETDATE
IF %SETDAY% LSS 1 GOTO SETDATE
IF %SETDAY% GTR 31 GOTO SETDATE
IF %SETYEAR% LSS 2019 GOTO SETDATE
IF %SETYEAR% GTR 2025 GOTO SETDATE
```

Comment: why not just add a value to it (making in non octal), like @Compo demonstrated below, else you could remove the leading `0` i.e `set setday=%setday =%`

Comment: You could simply use, `1%SETMONTH%` and `1%SETDAY%` for example. So `08` would become `108` , you would then remove `100` when necessary.

Comment: @Compo I just did this and it appears to be working. I kinda know why it is but need to learn more of the technical reasoning behind it. Any reason this would not work? `IF 1%SETMONTH% LSS 11 GOTO SETDATE`, `IF 1%SETMONTH% GTR 112 GOTO SETDATE` , `IF 1%SETDAY% LSS 11 GOTO SETDATE` , `IF 1%SETDAY% GTR 131 GOTO SETDATE` , `IF 1%SETYEAR% LSS 12019 GOTO SETDATE` , `IF 1%SETYEAR% GTR 12025 GOTO SETDATE`

Comment: The biggest flaw is that you're expecting the end user to follow your advice, using `Set /P` gives your end user free reign to enter nothing, or whatever the heck they want!

Comment: I see your point. Risk for my situation is minimal though. It is myself and a few select other that would be using. All tech users. That said, it also gets caught further in script when the task is getting created. I am open to better idea though. I have never like BAT files. I much prefer PS but cannot transition some things to it yet with Win7 Pro and Win7 Emb in our envirionment. PS Version is too old.

Comment: N. B.: To avoid problems with useless user input you could do something like `set "SETDAY="` before `set /P SETDAY=`, then `for /F "tokens=* delims=0 eol=0" %%N in ("0%SETDAY%") do set "SETDAY=%%N"`, and finally `set /A "DAY+=0"`; this would allow only numeric inputs (even with leading zeros), everything else results in a value of `0`; (this code might still cause trouble when the user enteres something containing `"` though, but using delayed expansion could even help then...)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post a solution that appears to be working for my needs. It doesn't account for every possible input but it does solve my issue with 08 and 09. It removes leading 0 if there is one and then it will process fine.

```
:SETDATE
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO Date must be 2 digit Month/Day and 4 digit Year
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P SETMONTH=Enter 2 digit month (01-12):
ECHO.
SET /P SETDAY=Enter 2 digit day (01-31):
ECHO.
SET /P SETYEAR=Enter 4 digit year (2019-2025):

IF %SETMONTH% == 0 (
    SET NEWMONTH=0
) ELSE (
    IF "%SETMONTH:~0,1%" == "0" (
        SET NEWMONTH=%SETMONTH:~1%    
    ) ELSE (
        SET NEWMONTH=%SETMONTH%
    )    
)
IF %SETDAY% == 0 (
    SET NEWDAY=0
) ELSE (
    IF "%SETDAY:~0,1%" == "0" (
        SET NEWDAY=%SETDAY:~1%    
    ) ELSE (
        SET NEWDAY=%SETDAY%
    )    
)
IF %SETYEAR% == 0 (
    SET NEWYEAR=0
) ELSE (
    IF "%SETYEAR:~0,1%" == "0" (
        SET NEWYEAR=%SETYEAR:~1%    
    ) ELSE (
        SET NEWYEAR=%SETYEAR%
    )    
)

IF %NEWMONTH% LSS 1 GOTO SETDATE
IF %NEWMONTH% GTR 12 GOTO SETDATE
IF %NEWDAY% LSS 1 GOTO SETDATE
IF %NEWDAY% GTR 31 GOTO SETDATE
IF %NEWYEAR% LSS 2019 GOTO SETDATE
IF %NEWYEAR% GTR 2025 GOTO SETDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't technically the type of answer you were looking for, I have decided to add it as an idea.

This is a standalone batch file intended to provide a GUI calendar for the end user to choose from. It uses PowerShell, and to the best of my knowledge should work with Windows 7, i.e. PowerShell 2.0.

```
<# :DSel
@Echo Off
Set "_="&For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP -C^
 "IEx([IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"') Do Set "_=%%A"
If Not Defined _ GoTo DSel
Echo You selected %_%
Pause
Exit /B
#>
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$form.Text = 'Select a date'
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,230)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $false
$calendar.MaxDate = ((Get-Date).AddYears(5)).AddDays(-1)
$calendar.MinDate = Get-Date
$calendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$form.Controls.Add($calendar)

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(38,165)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(113,165)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Today'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$form.ControlBox = $false
$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $date = $calendar.SelectionStart
    Write-Host $($date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
}
```

*As you have suggested you have knowledge of PowerShell, 'll leave it to you to make any required modifications to the PowerShell stuff.*